# "MP3 file format not valid. Zero duration. Seek will not function properly:" Error streaming big mp3 files with HLS

Tags: mp3, wowza, hsl

I'm experiencing the following error trying to stream a big MP3 file (2.6 GB) from a VOD application using HLS (wowza version is 4.1.2)

> ERROR server comment 2020-06-11 17:21:00 - - - - - 59.9 - - - - - - -
>
> - open : java.lang.Exception: MP3 file format not valid. Zero duration. Seek will not function properly: 5421.mp3|at
>   com.wowza.wms.mediareader.mp3.MediaReaderMP3.readMetadata(MediaReaderMP3.java:419)|at
>   com.wowza.wms.mediareader.mp3.MediaReaderMP3.open(MediaReaderMP3.java:160)|at
>   com.wowza.wms.httpstreamer.cupertinostreaming.file.HTTPStreamerCupertinoIndexFile.open(HTTPStreamerCupertinoIndexFile.java:292)|at
>   com.wowza.wms.httpstreamer.cupertinostreaming.httpstreamer.HTTPStreamerSessionCupertino.getIndex(HTTPStreamerSessionCupertino.java:119)|at
>   com.wowza.wms.httpstreamer.cupertinostreaming.httpstreamer.HTTPStreamerAdapterCupertinoStreamer.onPlaylist(HTTPStreamerAdapterCupertinoStreamer.java:2068)|

This is the ouptut of ffprobe on the file:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ffprobe:ffprobe xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:ffprobe='http://www.ffmpeg.org/schema/ffprobe' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.ffmpeg.org/schema/ffprobe ffprobe.xsd'>
        <streams>
            <stream index="0" codec_name="mp3" codec_long_name="MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)" codec_type="audio" codec_time_base="1/48000" codec_tag_string="[0][0][0][0]" codec_tag="0x0000" sample_fmt="fltp" sample_rate="48000" channels="2" channel_layout="stereo" bits_per_sample="0" r_frame_rate="0/0" avg_frame_rate="0/0" time_base="1/14112000" start_pts="324870" start_time="0.023021" duration_ts="1219277138688" duration="86400.024000" bit_rate="256000">
                <disposition default="0" dub="0" original="0" comment="0" lyrics="0" karaoke="0" forced="0" hearing_impaired="0" visual_impaired="0" clean_effects="0" attached_pic="0" timed_thumbnails="0"/>
                <tag key="encoder" value="Lavc58.35"/>
            </stream>
        </streams>

        <format filename="5421.mp3" nb_streams="1" nb_programs="0" format_name="mp3" format_long_name="MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)" start_time="0.023021" duration="86400.024000" size="2764801581" bit_rate="256000" probe_score="51">
            <tag key="encoder" value="Lavf58.20.100"/>
        </format>
    </ffprobe:ffprobe>
```

I tried to packetize the stream (as explained here https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-improve-playback-of-lower-latency-apple-hls-streams) without success. Is there any configuration needed on the server application?

Can anyone help me?

UPDATE: A smaller file (same bit rate, smaller duration, size a bit less than 2GB) is successfully played. Wowza server has 8 GB ram and 4 CPUs.

Comment: Are you able to update to a more recent version of wowza? 4.1.2 is quite old (most recent is 4.8.5) and may be contributing to your problems packetizing.

Comment: no, I cannot update wowza version

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to Wowza's MediaReader specifically in this case, but what may be a clue here is that the normal MP3 format doesn't actually contain a duration in the container.  It's just a series of MPEG frames, one after the other.

FFprobe can determine a duration by reading through the entire file and figuring out how many frames there are.  Wowza could do the same thing.  The fact that your smaller file (<2GB) works implies that Wowza is actually doing this, but may have a 2 GB limit... a common limit, since that's the max signed integer value.

If you could mux your MP3 stream into a container that supports a duration, that Wowza can also read, that may solve your issue.  Otherwise, try upgrading as @akaykay suggested.